# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<405>

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have a method located in class marked as `@Controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEvent(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("myEvent") Event event,
            BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventTypeId,
            @RequestParam(required = true) Integer selectedEventStatusId) {

        if (result.getErrorCount() > 1 ){
            return "eventDetailsAdd";
        }
        eventService.addEvent(event, selectedEventTypeId, selectedEventStatusId);
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("idEvent", event.getId());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "added correctly at " + new Date() );
        return "redirect:eventDetails";
    }
```

If I write following code:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/addEvent");
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);

        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

I see:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<405>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:549)
    ...
```

What's the problem, and how would I fix it?

**UPDATE**

if I write:

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/addEvent");
        request.param("selectedEventTypeId", "1");
        request.param("selectedEventStatusId", "1");

        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);

        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        result.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl("eventDetailsAdd"));
```

I see the same result.

**RESOLVED**

Bitman advice + add(by  Sotirios Delimanolis)

```
   request.param("selectedEventTypeId", "1");
   request.param("selectedEventStatusId", "1");
```

What will the Event event instance take from Spring in my case?

Comment: You haven't sent any request parameters.

Comment: How I can set Event event

Comment: You don't _set_ the `Event` argument. You generate your request with request parameters that Spring will use to create all your method arguments.

Comment: please read my update

Comment: The problem is that your call to your server does not lead to a code 200 "OK" status, but a code 405 "Method Not Allowed" status. You don't have a stack trace server-side ?

Comment: ok. What the Event event instance will take by spring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .get("/addEvent");
```

to

```
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/addEvent");
```

Because you're expecting `method = RequestMethod.POST` POST in controller
But your test is executing GET.

This is what HTTP Error 405 Method not allowed means

Comment: Although this is correct, it is not complete. OP will just get more errors.